# Converting two PNG-Images into numpy arrays results in two different shapes

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, image-processing, python-imaging-library

While converting PNG-Files into numpy arrays I noticed that the conversion sometimes resulted in different array shapes. While [the first image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v3mCD.png) has a three dimensional array shape (as most images do) [the second one](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vfmvr.png) has two dimensions. The images are both screenshots and have not been altered. Unfortunately the array shape really matters for my intended use.

I used the code below for the image conversion.

```
import numpy as np
import PIL.Image

img_path = ''  # Put the image path here

img_pil = PIL.Image.open(img_path)
img_array = np.asarray(img_pil)

print(img_array.shape)
```

My question is whether there is a way to align the shapes of the images.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If none of your images are colour, you might as well save memory and work in greyscale, so you could ensure that with:

```
im = Image.open(FILENAME).convert('L')
```

Or you could always go to colour with:

```
im = Image.open(FILENAME).convert('RGB')
```

Answer (score 0):

From what I've been able to see here: [Image processing with numpy](https://www.pythoninformer.com/python-libraries/numpy/numpy-and-images/), greyscale images(as it seems to be the case with the second image) are sometimes stored only in two dimensions since there is no need for saving three different colors for each pixel. This probably depends on how the image was created.

Comment: This seems logical. Is there a straight forward way to create images with matching shapes?

Comment: In my experience, most if not all pictures you create and save on your own will be in rgb(3 dimensions). You can make a function which "translates" them from two- to three-dimensional arrays.